# How can I disable the "Require authorization" for "Per-key cache invalidation" in AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Is there a way to disable the `Require authorization` value when deploying an API stage using CloudFormation?

Since I'm using OAuth with Cognito to protect the API, it is not possible to add the `InvalidateCache` policy as described here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-caching.html#invalidate-method-caching

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is not supported by CloudFormation as described here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/18794

The best I've come up with is to disable `Require Authorization` using the AWS CLI as part of the CI/CD pipeline after the stage has been deployed:

```
aws apigateway update-stage --rest-api-id [api-id] --stage-name [stage_name] --patch-operations \
op="replace",path="'the_resource_path/GET/caching/requireAuthorizationForCacheControl'",value="false"
```

Note that the resource path has to be escaped according to the rules described here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway/client/update_stage.html